# MySQL Python client got 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

This error happens to both `pymysql` and `mysql-connector-python`. But not to the MySQL shell. MySQL shell is able to login via `mysql -u root -p` normally.

The error looks like:

```
In [1]: import mysql.connector

In [2]: mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
   ...:   host="localhost",
   ...:   user="root",
   ...:   passwd="password"
   ...: )

ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Or

```
In [8]: import pymysql.cursors

In [9]: connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
   ...:                              user='root',
   ...:                              password='password',
   ...:                              db='db',
   ...:                              cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

...
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Python version 3.7, running on Mac OSX 10.14. MySQL version 8.0.16.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I searched all answers on the site. Didn't find a fix, thus want to document this solution to help other people running into similar situation.

The culprit of `pymysql` stopping working should be upgrading to MySQL 8. MySQL 8 has stronger password authentication than the previous 5.7. Downgrading from 8 to 5.7 is a lot of pain that I don't want to go through. A simple attempt to revert to legacy authentication via editing `my.cnf` turned out not working.

Then I read this blog: https://blog.csdn.net/zoe9698/article/details/78171465 (it's in Chinese).

Basically it's saying that the user shouldn't be `root`. A Python connection is considered "remote" thus logging as `root` is prohibited.

So just create another user and grant all the privileges to it.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Replacing the `root` in the code with `user`, the error is gone.

Comment: I have the same problem and tried your solution but it didn't work for me... if I find something i'll post it here